fix a value for a line chart in Power BI
I have a line and column chart in PowerBi that shows in the columns the sales in each month. i want to show in the line y-axis the total average of the year; I mean, a only value to get a straight line across my visual.
I want to get Something like this
I tried to modify my average measure to remove the month filter, because is what i think is affecting my line, but its still being modified by the filter (and i need to conserve that filter for the columns)
i tried these measures but none of them worked:

AVERAGEX(
VALUES('Calendar'[Month]),
CALCULATE([Sales])
)

CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(VALUES('Calendar'[Month]),CALCULATE([Sales])),REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar'[Year])
)



This is the data that I used for testing



date
value




2024/1/1
100


2024/2/1
200


2024/3/1
300


2024/4/1
400


2024/5/1
500


2024/6/1
600


2024/7/1
700


2024/8/1
800


2024/9/1
900


2024/10/1
1000



Then I created a calendar table and created relationship with fact table
At last, you can create a measure
MEASURE =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[value] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) ),
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'date'[month] ), ALL ( 'date' ) )
)



you are welcome. pls accept it as an answer.
